# Facebook friend show on profile

Tags: facebook, facebook-friends

If I'm a friend with another on Facebook, does it have to show up on both friends profiles unless hidden?

What I'm trying to ask is that is it possible that if I created a friendship with you, and you accepted, does it only show friends on one profile and not the other?

Answer (score -1):

You can always change who can see your friends on Facebook but you can not change it for your friend or someone in your friend list. Here's how you can change settings for your account:

1. Open Facebook from your web browser
2. Click the triangle in the upper right to open the menu, then select
   Settings
3. Click Privacy in the left-hand column
4. In the "How People Can Find and Contact You" section, select "Who
   can see your friends list." Click it.
5. In the drop-down menu, select who you would like to see your friends
   list. Select one option from this list:
   **Public**: Anyone can see your friends list
   **Friends**: Only your friends can see your friends list
   **Only Me**: Only you can see your friends list
   **Custom**: You can select exactly who can and can't see your friends list. When you
   click Custom, you can enter specific lists or names under "Share with" to
   let them see your friends list or "Don't share with" to prevent them
   from seeing your friends list.
6. When you're done, click Save changes to save your custom settings
7. Click Close on the right to save your settings

Comment: Can you tell me if I had you showing as a friend on my Facebook page - does that guarantee that I'm a friend on your page whether you have your friends being shown or not.  Can a Friendship only go one way?

Comment: This doesn't answer what OP has asked.

Comment: Yes. If I'm being shown as a friend on your profile, then it essentially means that I'm a friend in your friend list as well whether you show or hide it.